# Order of the Workbook.LinkSources Method Arrary in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-linksources-method-excel

The link states that the Workbook.Linksources Method returns the name of the link source in array. How is the array organized? Are the link names alphabetical?